# Can someone explain what's happening here (classes and constructors/destructors)?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Person
{
    string name;

    public:
        Person():name("")
        {
            cout << "Person default ctor\n";
        }
        Person(const string& name_in):name(name_in)
        {
            cout << "Person string ctor: " << name << "\n";
        }
        ~Person()
        {
            cout << "Person dtor: " << name << "\n";
        }
        string get_name()
        {
            return name;
        }
};

class Professor:public Person
{
    int office;

    public:
        Professor(const string& name_in, int office_in):Person(name_in), office(office_in)
        {
            cout << "Professor string ctor: " << get_name() << endl;
        }
        ~Professor()
        {
            cout << "Professor dtro: " << get_name() << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Person alice("Alice");
    Professor bob("Bob", 10);

    return 0;
}
```

I would assume that the output should be:

```
Person string ctor: Alice

Person dtor: Alice

Professor string ctor: Bob

Professor dtor: Bob
```

Since it seems like that should logically follow from the structure of the program.  However, the real output is:

```
Person string ctor: Alice

Person string ctor: Bob

Professor string ctor: Bob

Professor dtor: Bob

Person dtor: Bob

Person dtor: Alice
```

Can someone explain why this is?  What am I not understanding about classes/constructors/destructors that's making me come up with the wrong output?

Comment: What would the use of an object be if it got destroyed right after it got created? Objects are destroyed at the end of the scope in the reverse order of creation. Derived classes construct their base classes first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `Professor` derives from `Person`. This means that every instance of `Professor` implicitly contains an instance of `Person` (observe how you're calling `Person(name_in)` in `Professor`'s constructor). This implicit instance will automatically get destroyed when the `Professor` object is being destroyed.

This explains why you see:

```
Person string ctor: Bob
Person dtor: Bob
```

As to the ordering of the destructor calls, the variables are destroyed in the *reverse* order of construction. This explains why Bob is destroyed before Alice:

```
Person string ctor: Alice
Professor string ctor: Bob
Professor dtor: Bob
Person dtor: Alice
```

Comment: Thanks! So where in the program are the destructors called?  I would think that it would happen when the object is initialized, but that doesn't appear to be so.

Comment: @BobJohn: The destructors get called at the end of the enclosing block (here, just before the `return 0`).

Comment: @BobJohn, When allocated on the stack, when they go out of scope. When allocated on the free store, whenever `delete` is used. If they were destroyed right after being initialized, you wouldn't be able to use objects for more than one statement, which defeats the point.

Comment: OK, that makes sense.  But how can I tell when they go out of scope?  It seems arbitrary to say "at the end of main," unless I'm not understanding something about the stack frame.

Comment: @BobJohn, When the ending curly brace is reached. The curly braces define scopes. You can even use them arbitrarily: `int main() {int a; {Person p;} //can't use p now, but can still use a }`

Comment: No, it's not arbitrary at all. For automatic (i.e. stack-based) objects, the destructor is called at the `}` which closes the block where they are declared. This is a slight simplification, but is close enough for most purposes.

Comment: @NPE: To clarify something about your first comment: Technically speaking, the end of the enclosing block is the `}` which is after `return 0;` not "just before" it.

Comment: @NikBougalis This now makes more sense.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Because Professor is inherited it will call the base class constructor when it is created. That is why `person Bob` is printed.

As for the reverse destruction, this is because objects a destroyed in reverse order to what they were created.

Answer (score 0):

Professor "is a" Person, so when you call the Professor constructor, the constructor of its base class - which is Person - will be called first.

Similiar to the desturcter, but in reversed order. The destructor of the child class will be called first, and then the base class.

Also, destructors are only called when the objects are destroyed, which in your case, only happens when the current scope is end.